# How to initialize firebaseConfig dynamically in Angular

Tags: angular, firebase

I need to initialize firebaseConfig in my angular application, i need to do all this in clientside.

This is my environment.ts

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import axios from 'axios';

interface Environment {
  production: boolean;
  firebaseConfig: {
    apiKey: string;
    authDomain: string;
    projectId: string;
    storageBucket: string;
    messagingSenderId: string;
    appId: string;
  };
}

export async function getEnvironment(): Promise<Environment> {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get('https://us-central1-my_api');
    // const environment: Environment = firebaseConfig:{
    const environment: Environment = {
      production: true,
      firebaseConfig: {
        apiKey: response.data.apiKey,
        authDomain: "",
        projectId: "",
        storageBucket: "..",
        messagingSenderId: "",
        appId: ":::",
      }
    };
    return environment;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    throw new Error('Failed to load environment');
  }
}
```

I tried to fetch configuration using app-config.services.ts.